# int a = (int) ((0.7 + 0.1) * 10). Why a = 7?

Tags: java

I have question to everybody.

```
int a = (int) ((0.7 + 0.1) * 10)
```

After executing of this code, a = 7.
I can`t understand why, because (0.7+0.1)=0.8 and 0.8*10=8.
Can anybody tell me why?
Thanks!

Comment: Try printing the result of `0.7 + 0.1`, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: The result is 0. All the same I don`t understand why a = 7

Comment: @user2535193 How are you printing that? Post the code that's responsible of printing.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The issue is that neither 0.1 nor 0.7 can be represented exactly as `double`:

- `0.1` gets represented as approximately `0.10000000000000000555`.
- `0.7` gets represented as approximately `0.69999999999999995559`.

Their sum is approximately `0.79999999999999993339`. Multiplied by ten and truncated, this gives `7`.

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is an excellent read on the subject.

Comment: Most succinct and precise answer on internet.

Answer (score 6):

It's float arithmetic, it gets floored.

What's happening here is that (0.1+0.7) is *really* close to 0.8 but it's not *actually* 0.8, when you multiply it by 10 you get 7.9999... , when you floor that, you get 7.

Answer (score 3):

The decimal portion of `int`s in Java is truncated. You can either make `x` and `y` floating point variables or just cast them to float and cast them back to get an int as the final result.